# exporting data from excel to R

Tags: r

```
 library(readxl)
DATA <- read_excel("C:/Users/M.Daniyal/Desktop/coronoa/DATA.xlsx", 
     col_types = c("numeric", "numeric"), 
     na = "NA")
 View(DATA)
 plot(x,y)
```

Error in plot(x, y) : object 'x' not found

its giving error that x is not found. how can I resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

The object created is 'DATA'.  The columns in that object is only accessible inside the environment of 'DATA' unless we `attach` (not recommended) to create the column names also as objects in the global environment.

With the current code, can use either extractors (`[[` or `$`)

```
plot(DATA$x, DATA$y)
```

Or a formula object

```
plot(y ~ x, DATA)
```

or `with`

```
with(DATA, plot(x, y))
```